# CNN weights greater than 1

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, conv-neural-network, weights

I am looking to visualize a class activation map (CAM) on my 1D data with Keras.

I found that CAM values were not included between 0 and 1. After searching I found that some of the last layer weights were greater than 1 (6.240733, 0.15269098, ..., 0.5547908 , 1.6323686).

I thought that the weights should not exceed 1, Am I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Usually, for most of the neural networks architectures, there is no constrains on the weights, the weights can take any values on the real line. There is no reason to constrain the weights. If you want neural network layer to return certain kind of values (e.g. between zero and one), then you can always use activation function for it.

Comment: It seems strange because I am using a relu activation for each conv layer

Comment: @Noura Why is that strange? Relus are only restricted to be non-negative; they are not restricted to be less than 1.

Comment: @ReinstateMonica, what activation function I have to use to restrict weights less than 1?

Comment: @Noura **no** activation function restricts the weights. Activation function is applied to the outcome returned by some layer (in simplest case it's `data*weights`).

Comment: Is it normal to have very high CAM values (between -10 and 30)?

Comment: @Noura weights can take *any* values. There is no "typical" values, as it depends on your data and architecture of the model you are using.

Answer (score 0):

This is fine. Ultimately, your neural network is layers of feature extraction followed by a regression on those extracted features. A more routine regression has no restrictions on the coefficients, and neither does that last layer of your neural network. It might just be that a small change to some of the neurons in that final hidden layer results in a large (magnitude exceeding $1$) change in the outcome. So be it.

If your concern is that the output neuron will give a value above $1$ or below $0$ (so no longer having an interpretation as a probability), note that this can happen when all of the weights are contained within an interval like $(0,1)$. This is a known issue of the [linear probability model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_probability_model). If you want to transform output values to be restricted to an interval like $(0,1)$ so they can be interpreted as probabilities, various activation functions (quite analogous to link functions in generalized linear models) are viable. This is where you might see `sigmoid` in the output layer of neural network code, though many functions are viable.